# Using pi as router

Tags: networking, pi-2, vpn

What is the minimal config needed, to be able to specify some static route for network subset (eg 10.199.0.0/16), so that my raspberry redirects to internal PC?

`LAPTOP` (pink) is connecting via VPN to `VPN SERVER`, and `RASPBERRY` address is directly accessible via VPN. `INTERNAL PC` address is not directly accessible via `VPN SERVER`. `INTERNAL PC` is accessible from `RASPBERRY`. What do I need to install on `RASPBERRY`, so that i can set static routes for 10.199.0.0/16 to go to RASPBERRY (or somehow to be proxified), so that `INTERNAL PC` is accessible from `LAPTOP` via VPN?

I would like to skip installing additional VPN on `RASPBERRY` and then to have to do VPN over VPN.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you noted you will use a route to the internal pc using the RasPi as router. So you must have a different subnet for the internal pc and using the RasPi as gateway to that subnet. For this the RasPi needs at least two interfaces, one connected to the virtual private network 10.199.0.0/16 and one connected to the subnet of the internal pc.

For my example I assume the RasPi is wireless connected to the VPN servers access point on subnet 10.199.0.0/16 with ip address 10.199.0.2/16 on its interface **wlan0**. Because it is working as gateway to the internal pcs network, this must be a static ip address so it can be addressed.

To the internal pc the RasPi is wired connected on its interface **eth0** to subnet 192.168.0.0/24 with static ip address 192.168.0.1.

Assuming all connections are working at least between the direct connected devices you have to set some static routes. I will use the linux [iproute2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2) syntax for all examples.

On the laptop set:

```
laptop ~$ sudo ip route add 192.168.0.0/24 via 10.199.0.2
```

On the RasPi enable ip forward:

```
rpi ~$ sudo bash -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward'
```

You must have at least two routes to direct connected networks, something similar to this:

```
rpi ~$ ip route
10.199.0.0/16 dev wlan0 proto static scope link src 10.199.0.2 metric 303
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto static scope link src 192.168.0.1 metric 202
```

On the internal pc set:

```
pc ~$ sudo ip route add 10.199.0.0/16 via 192.168.0.1
```

This are only transient settings to show the principle. There are some other methods to set routing and ip forwarding depending on the networking environment you are using. You don't tell us about it so look how to set up it persistent on your different devices. I couldn't test it and hope I haven't overseen something.

Comment: do I have to use 2 interfaces? Currently I can use raspberry as SSH jumpbox with single interface (LAN) and this one works without problem?

Comment: @BojanVukasovic What do you mean with jump box? Where to jump? For routing between two networks you always need two interfaces. That's by specification of routing.

Comment: It seems that what I described was actually not correct, since I can ping INTERNALPC via VPN. I guess that actually firewall prevents accessing INTERNALPC ports (eg SSH) from VPN, but internally it is allowed. So that is actually what I needed.

Comment: Is it possible to use raspberry as some proxy, so that when I request access to some port on `INTERNAL PC` from `LAPTOP`, `INTERNAL PC` thinks that `RASPBERRY` is accessing it and not `LAPTOP`?

Comment: @BojanVukasovic In your question you asked for routing. If you have other questions, then please create new ones.